# ggplot default theme_grey() not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
df=read.csv("TestData.csv", header=TRUE,sep = ";")
xymelt <- melt(df, id.vars = "Date")

ggplot(xymelt, aes(x = Date, y = value, colour = variable, group=1)) +geom_line()
+facet_wrap( ~ variable)+theme_grey()
```

The above is the code that I used I am getting the correct plot but I don't have neither colored grey panels or white grid lines I want the default theme why isn't it working ?

[image: plot]

Does it have to do with the fact that I melted the data ? or the grouping ? Please Help !!

Comment: Restart your session and try again. Most likely some other function modified  themes/plotting defaults.

Comment: add + scale_fill_grey()

Comment: Are you running any other graphics packages?  I've seen cowplot modify ggplot2 defaults (for the better, in my opinion).

Comment: no, I'll post the whole code in the hope that someone can help, it's weird because theme_bw() works !

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

df<-melt(iris)

ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(data=df, aes(variable, value, fill=Species)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Species) + scale_fill_grey()
```

Comment: I believe you, do you think it's the group = 1 thing ?

Answer (score -2):

Check the contrast setting on your monitor and try looking at it on another monitor, the grey color can easily get washed out if the contrast is set too high.